# What's the "Drupal" way of creating image links?

Tags: 7, media, navigation

I know that the correct way to create links in Drupal is to use `l($text, $path, array $options = array())`. But that only allows for text links. Is there a similar function for creating images that link, or is it OK to just write out the HTML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`l()` allows for HTML too, you just need to pass it as one of the options:

```
$link = l($image_html, $path, array('html' => TRUE));
```

That'll stop the first parameter being passed through `check_plain()`, so the the full HTML you pass in will be wrapped in the `<a>` tag.

I'd advise using this method if the alternative is writing the link out manually, you get the benefit of automatic alias-translation and it's less prone to small errors in the HTML (of which I for one always make loads).

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7 will even generate that $image_html for you

Comment: Thanks; I was aware of (and use) theme_image(); just wasn't sure about l(). I must have completely blocked out that part of the API page, because I did look.